# java 8 Map.merge is thread safe?

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainTest
{
    static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();

    public static void incr()
    {
        map.merge("counter", 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    public static void decr()
    {
        map.merge("counter", -1, Integer::sum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        map.put("counter", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    incr();
                }
            });
            t1.join();
            t1.start();

            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    decr();
                }
            });
            t2.join();
            t2.start();
        }
      System.out.println(map);
    }

}
```

The result is `{counter=-2}` when main method is run.
Why is it not 0?

Comment: No. Why would it be? `HashMap` is not threadsafe therefore no method on `HashMap` is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Javadoc of `merge` on the `Map` interface says:

> The default implementation **makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method**. Any implementation providing atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its concurrency properties.

While `HashMap` overrides the default implementation, it has no documentation regarding concurrency properties of that implementation, but it does have this general statement:

> Note that **this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally

Therefore it's not thread safe.

P.S., it's not clear why you call `t1.join()` and `t2.join()` before you start the corresponding thread.

If you reverse the calls

```
    t1.join();
    t1.start();
```

to

```
    t1.start();
    t1.join();
```

and

```
    t2.join();
    t2.start();
```

to

```
    t2.start();
    t2.join();
```

you'll get an output of 0. Of course if you do that, there will be no concurrent modification at all, since each thread will start after the previous thread dies.

Another alternative is to synchronize the `map.merge` calls externally:

```
public static void incr()
{
    synchronized(map) {map.merge("counter", 1, Integer::sum);}
}

public static void decr()
{
    synchronized(map) {map.merge("counter", -1, Integer::sum);}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It’s a bit strange to ask for the thread safety of a particular single method modifying a data structure like `HashMap` which is documented not to be thread safe *in general*.

When you want to modify a map concurrently, you have to look for an implementation which supports concurrent updates, which is usually shown by implementing `ConcurrentMap`. For these maps, even the `default` implementation would be sufficient, as it is implemented atop the other interface methods, which are guaranteed to be thread safe. But if you want *atomicity* guaranteed, you need an implementation overriding the method with an appropriate implementation, e.g. [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

> `merge`
>
> … The entire method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this Map.

To fix and simplify your example:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> map.merge("counter", -1, Integer::sum));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> map.merge("counter",  1, Integer::sum));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Note that in your original code, you’re calling `join()` *before* start, which has no effect. Since you’re not doing a `join()` after `start()`, your code bears the possibility to print the `map` before all threads have finished, so it could print a nonzero value, even if `HashMap` was thread safe.

Doing the `join()` after `start()` like in the code above will correctly wait for the completion, but allows at most two concurrent update operations.

To raise the concurrency, you should abandon the manual thread creation:

```
ExecutorService threadPool
    = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    threadPool.execute(() -> map.merge("counter", -1, Integer::sum));
    threadPool.execute(() -> map.merge("counter",  1, Integer::sum));
}
threadPool.shutdown();
threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
System.out.println(map);
```

This allows a concurrency higher than two, but since the worker threads might be able to execute this simple task as fast as your loop can schedule new jobs, the resulting concurrency might be still close to two.